# Stack Overflow rendered inside an Ad

Tags: bug, site-ads

I was on a [random python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) question on Stack Overflow, when I saw a network ad. It was about Music SE. I clicked on it, and an ad got replaced with a tiny iframe with Stack Overflow page inside it. Tiny version of Stack Overflow knows who I am, but it doesn't really do much apart from just being there.

[image]

Pocking with dev tool I saw that some errors happening inside google_ads_iframe:

```
Uncaught TypeError: StackExchange.ready is not a function
    at ?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmusic.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F91112%2Fwhat-is-your-preferred-method-to-figure-out-the-key:4168

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>').
```

I cannot reproduce this with any other ads, and gods of random don't show me that Music SE add anymore.

Not sure if it's really a reproducible bug, just wanted to share a Stack Overflow inside Stack Overflow.

Comment: The real bug is that the ad should be displayed on Meta. Because...it's *so Meta*.